# How to implement model class for multiple values in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift

Here I am having `value` in JSON in which for some of multiple key value pairs it returning string and for some it is returning array here in custom attributes array in first dictionary in that `value` key value pair the data present is different and in the second dictionary `value` key value pair is different here then how to implement the model class for inside array for different key values ?

```
struct MediaGallery {

    let id : Int
    let mediaType : String
    let label : Any
    let position : Int
    let disabled : Any
    let file : String

    init(dict : [String:Any]) {
        self.id = (dict["id"] as? Int)!
        self.mediaType = (dict["media_type"] as? String)!
        self.label =  dict["label"]!
        self.position = (dict["position"] as? Int)!
        self.disabled = dict["disabled"]!
        self.file = (dict["file"] as? String)!
    }
}
struct AttributeList {

    let label : String
    let value : String
    let code : String

    init(dict : [String:Any]){

        self.label = (dict["label"])! as! String
        self.value = (dict["value"])! as! String
        self.code = (dict["code"])! as! String
    }
}
struct DetailsListAttribute {

    let attributeCode : String
    let value : Any

    init?(dict : [String:Any]) {

        self.attributeCode = dict["attribute_code"] as! String
        print(self.attributeCode)
        if let values = dict["value"] as? String {
            self.value = values
        }
        else {
            if let arr = dict["value"] as? [[String:Any]]{
                var filterArr = [AttributeList]()
                for obj in arr {
                    filterArr.append(AttributeList(dict: obj))
                }
                self.value = filterArr
            } else {
                self.value = [AttributeList]()
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: it 's not it is different I am unable to implement model class for custom attributes inside value in first two dictionaries @LouisLeung

Comment: You should use something like SwiftyJSON / ObjectMapper / Codable protocol to make ur parsing easier

Comment: Without third party libraries is it possible to implement ? @Tj3n

Comment: Avoid sending screenshot of your JSON, please send the whole JSON as it will be in production.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried multiple JSON-mapping frameworks that were mentioned in Tj3n comment. They all have pros and cons.  Apple suggests you to follow the recommendation given [here](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37). Also you should check [`Codable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable) protocol (swift 4 is required).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest please save some time by using this great GIT Library [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper) . it will help you to model your object and convert your model objects (classes and structs) to JSON and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I don't have the whole JSON, and it doesn't seem clear to me.

But here is how you can parse and create your model Class easily in Swift with the Codable protocol.

You can read more about it and/or some examples, tutorials : [Ultimate Guide](http://benscheirman.com/2017/06/ultimate-guide-to-json-parsing-with-swift-4/).

Briefly, what is the Codable protocol ?

You don't need third party library anymore in order to parse and set the json data to your model class.
You juste have to create your class like the JSON is represented. And according to the key-name, it will create the class, properties and everything for you.

Here is an example with your JSON, I don't know if I understood your JSON formatting, but you got the trick :

```
struct Response: Codable {
    let ca: [CustomAttribute]?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case ca = "custom_attributes"
    }
}

struct CustomAttribute: Codable {
    let code: String?
    let value: [Value]?
    
    struct Value: Codable {
        let label: String?
        let value: String?
        let code: String?
        
        let avg: String?  // I don't know how your value array is composed
        let count: Int?   // I don't know how your value array is composed
    }
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case code = "attribute_code"
        case avg = "avg_rating_percent"
    }
}
```

For me, it looks like something like that.

I don't see the whole JSON, but imagine you have the whole JSON as the Response Struct, it contains several objects, like the CustomAttribute Array for example.
Then you can define the CustomAttribute structure, and add as many properties as the JSON has.

Anyway, you can call it this way :

When you have the response from your API call, you can go :

```
if let data = response.data {
         let decoder = JSONDecoder()
         let response = try! decoder.decode(Response.self, from: data)
         print("Only printing the Custom Attribute : \(response.ca!)")
}
```

I decode the whole json data as an Object Response (like my Struct).
And I pass to my response callback, or

Answer (score 0):

this might be late but I think this will helps others

The model class which are varies for frameworks like SwiftyJSON, simple swift class, Gloss or swift codable (Swift 4). you can easily generate model class online with your customization [jsoncafe.com](http://www.jsoncafe.com/)